# Is this a decent home-made mutex implementation? Criticism? Potential Problems?

Tags: c, mutex

I'm wondering if anyone sees anything that would likely cause problems in this code.  I know there are other ways/API calls I could used to have done this, but I'm trying to lay the foundation for my own platform independant? / cross-platform mutex framework.

Obviously I need to do some #ifdef's and define some macros for the Win32 Sleep() and GetCurrentThreadID() calls...

```
typedef struct aec {
    unsigned long long lastaudibleframe; /* time stamp of last audible frame */
    unsigned short aiws; /* Average mike input when speaker is playing */
    unsigned short aiwos; /*Average mike input when speaker ISNT playing */
    unsigned long long t_aiws, t_aiwos; /* Internal running total */
    unsigned int c_aiws, c_aiwos; /* Internal counters */
    unsigned long lockthreadid;
    int stlc; /* Same thread lock count */
} AEC;

char lockecho( AEC *ec ) {
    unsigned long tid=0;
    static int inproc=0;
    while (inproc) {
        Sleep(1);
    }
    inproc=1;
    if (!ec) {
        inproc=0;
        return 0;
    }
    tid=GetCurrentThreadId();
    if (ec->lockthreadid==tid) {
        inproc=0;
        ec->stlc++;
        return 1;
    }
    while (ec->lockthreadid!=0) {
        Sleep(1);
    }
    ec->lockthreadid=tid;
    inproc=0;
    return 1;
}

char unlockecho( AEC *ec ) {
    unsigned long tid=0;
    if (!ec)
        return 1;
    tid=GetCurrentThreadId();
    if (tid!=ec->lockthreadid)
        return 0;
    if (tid==ec->lockthreadid) {
        if (ec->stlc>0) {
            ec->stlc--;
        } else {
            ec->lockthreadid=0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not, AFAIK you can't implement a mutex with plain C code without some low-level [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) operations ([RMW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93modify%E2%80%93write),  [Test and Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set)... etc).. In your particular example, consider what happens if a context switch interrupts the first thread before it gets a chance to set `inproc`, then the second thread will resume and set it to `1` and now both threads "think" they have exclusive access to the struct.. this is just one of many things that could go wrong with your approach.

Also note that even if a thread gets a chance to set `inproc`, assignment is not guranteed to be atomic (it could be interrupted in the middle of assigning the variable).

Comment: I guess in the back of my mind, I thought about the context switch interrupting the setting of the static inproc, but I thought, "man, I'd need another variable to "lock" inproc....so basically since the particular kernel on which the code is running controls the execution, any atomic operations would have to be exposed as APIs? I know windows has a bunch; I was just trying to see if it was possible to do it without API calls.

Comment: “AFAIK you can't implement a mutex with plain C code without some low-level atomic operations” http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm : … a concurrent programming algorithm for mutual exclusion that allows two processes to share a single-use resource without conflict, using only shared memory for communication

Comment: @PascalCuoq "provided that changes to the turn, flag[0], and flag[1] variables propagate immediately and atomically"

Comment: @mux See also the “Note” section. The article pre-dates modern implementations of multi-core/CPU and was written for a simplified model of them when they were exceedingly rare. But the memory barriers  that need to be added to make it work nowadays are not “atomic operations”.

Answer (score 1):

As [mux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051930/134633) points out, your proposed code is incorrect due to many race conditions.  You could solve this using atomic instructions like "Compare and Set", but you'll need to define those separately for each platform anyway.  You're better off just defining a high-level "Lock" and "Unlock" interface, and implementing *those* using whatever the platform provides.